# Exact difference Between Motion JPEG and JPEG , Embedded and multimedia codec

Tags: camera, sensors, codec, multimedia

I kept my head in many of the links and website but failed to get the answer. I hate to ask this, I know JPEG compression, it makes only compressed Images. Even Motion JPEG makes compressed Images I-frames . My question is what is difference. I am writing an application for camera which need to send video but my camera unit supports jpeg and  mjpeg. whats the advantage of motion JPEG over JPEG. Thanks for any advise

I found 
[V4L2 difference between JPEG and MJPEG pixel formats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32836312/v4l2-difference-between-jpeg-and-mjpeg-pixel-formats)
http://www.axis.com/in/en/learning/web-articles/technical-guide-to-network-video/video-compression

The First link mean that the capture rate can be made high with MJPEG but the size of images will be same.
The second links confirms that there is no difference between MJPEG and JPEG compression.
If the above conclusions are true then i can open the mjpeg frame on any image viewer, But i can't as told in first link

Answer (score 6):

JPEG is a single-page file format. Motion JPEG is a motion video adaptation of the JPEG standard for still photos. MJPEG treats a video stream as a series of still photos, compressing each frame individually, and uses no interframe compression.

The advantage of using the JPEG compression is that it has low complexity while doing a decent job of compression. MJPEG is simply extending the single frame format to a series of frames.